# How to wrap a href inside div wrapper using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to do the following:

Wrap div containers around every a href with the class .testclass.

I have been looking on jQuery's (jquery-3.1.1) wrapInner(); wrapAll(); functions, but no success.

Example code here:

```
<a class="testclass" href="test">test</a>
<script>
    $('.testclass').wrapAll('<div class="container-fluid"></div>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.wrapAll` will wrap all selected elements with a single element, `div` in your case. use `.wrap` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.testclass').wrap('<div class="container-fluid"></div>');
});
```

here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shirandror/znoysudn/)

Comment: what jquery version?

Comment: you can see in the fiddle, its jquery 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.replaceWith()`:

```
$(".testclass").each(function(){
  var $clone = $(this).clone();  
  var $container = $("<div></div>");
  $container.addClass('container-fluid');
  $container.append($clone);
  $(this).replaceWith($container);
});
```